# Conservation of angular momentum on a drone

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, aircraft

As I understand, a drone turns horizontally using conservation of angular momentum, accelerating rotors going to one side and deaccelerating the others. All the books I have seen about this say the angular momentum of the whole system is the sum of the angular moments of the different parts, so the angular momentum of the whole drone would be the angular momentum of the body plus the ones from the rotors. My question is, does the different axis of the rotation of the rotors to that of the body change anything? Can I calculate the angular momentum of the rotors using their individual axis and then sum all up with that of the drone body to find the total momentum and use this equation to find how the change in one change the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add up the angular momentum L of the motor-propeller assemblies and the main body to get a total L. It doesn’t matter that they’re in different places; angular momentum is independent of position.

But that’s not entirely why a drone rotates. The much larger effect is “prop torque” due to the propellers pushing on the air. This effect is why helicopters need tail rotors; it’s much larger than the angular momentum effect.